# How to use WP_rewrite?

Tags: functions, rewrite-rules

I need to add the following rewrite commend to WordPress `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to do this by a function? i.e., how to do it by use wp_rewrite in `function.php`?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress generates its `.htaccess` rules by `WP_Rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules()` method. It passes output through the `mod_rewrite_rules` filter, which allows you to edit it.

To make the new rules be written you will also need to call "hard" reset with `flush_rewrite_rules( true )` call.